# Increase space in C drive without deleting any other drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

My c drive on windows 10 has completely run out of space. It has <200 mb of space remaining. I want to add more space. I tried the disk Management. It doesn't work. Nor does any other external partition manager. Aomei partition manager seems to have this option, but in premium mode. One method I found that might work, was deleting d drive(next to c) and adding it to c. But I have everything installed in D drive so deleting it will not be a viable option.

My partitions look like this:
[image]

Comment: “I tried the disk partition.”—what exactly do you mean by that? // Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: https://ibb.co/hfdXHMk

Comment: Please add information like that directly to your question, using the provided image upload function. // Have you checked yet whether it is feasible to move away files from _C:_? Maybe use TreeSize Free (a portable version exists) to find out where the space went. // You may be able to gain some breathing room by (temporarily) disabling hibernation: `powercfg -h off`.

Comment: Why did you create so many tiny partitions in the first place? There is no added security or resistance to virus attack or device failure, just a whole set of "interesting" hurdles you made for yourself to climb. If you want 'data separation' make a new folder ;)  It looks like you might have a chance to copy the contents of D to E, delete D & expand C. You can only expand to space immediately to the right of any given volume, without some serious juggling. I would still make sure everything is properly backed up before you start.

Comment: @DanielB I have installed all my apps in D drive, although the I noticed the Appdata takes a lot of space( 14 GB )

Comment: @Tetsujin I updated the image.

Comment: you can use a 3rd party tool to resize your partitions, like epm: https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html  Always back up any important data before you start though

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/questions/1365677/how-to-extend-the-primary-boot-c-drive-partition-extend-option-grayed-out/1365681#1365681

Comment: I've done this plenty times with AIOMEI partition manager standard (free version). The key is to do the actions one at a time, let it complete and then do the next. So: Resize partition D, commit, move partition D to the right, commit, resize partition C, commit.

Comment: @Prateekp - You would need to delete one of the partitions in order to extend your system partition. AppData is suppose to be used. I would advise trying to shrink or otherwise prevent it from using disk space.

Comment: You have a backup? These things go wrong, you know ..

Comment: **I second the BACKUP** Do not proceed to modify any of your partitions without creating **and testing** a backup first